# How to select an image in Carousel and go to next view in iPhone

Tags: ios, icarousel

I'm making an iPhone app which consists of carousel. Please can anyone tell how we perform an action on selected image of Carousel.

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)crsl didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index { }
```

I'm trying to implement this but its not giving correct result please can anyone tell correct implementation of this

thanks

Comment: Have you set iCarousel's DataSource And Delegate?

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to do on selecting an item?

Comment: going to next view,saving that image etc anything that we can perform on an button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the DataSource and Delegate of iCarousel like this

[image]

And than in .h file set your ViewController Delegate for your iCarousel

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iCarousel.h"

@interface iCarouselViewController : UIViewController<iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel;

@end
```

And in .m file write the delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndex` like this

```
    -(void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    UIImage * img = [images objectAtIndex:index];

    ImageViewController *aImageViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];

    aImageViewController.image = img;   //this code is used to send image to another view not tested

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aImageViewController];
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

//this code used for present second-view controller that display selected image
    navigationController.topViewController.title = @"Greeting's";
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController               animated:YES];
    [navigationController release];

}
```

Comment: Your welcome. If encounter any problem let me know. and i have not tested image passing code but view code is tested.

Comment: hey hii dilip i have an issue how can i change the view of iCarousel .. i mean the default screen shows starting of iCarousel from mid of screen of phone .i want to change its position so that it can be start from beginning of screen of phone hope u got my point

Answer (score 0):

once try like this,

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[menuViews objectAtIndex:index]]];
        _reflectionView =[[[ReflectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];
        UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:14];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = index;
        [_reflectionView addSubview:button];

    return _reflectionView;
}
```

in above code menuViews is images array.

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);//based on tag value you can do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: While this works, why do you need to add an button. There is already delegate methods provided for viewSelection